# Getting links inside divs with Html Agility pack

Tags: parsing, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

i am getting links inside divs from a website with console application using Html Agility pack, my question is, what i am doing is crawling or parsing, i mean getting those links from a website with Html agility pack is parsing or crawling?

Comment: [quora.com: What is the difference between crawling, parsing and scraping?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-crawling-parsing-and-scraping)

Comment: I would not call it crawling, unless it is recursive. If you are extracting all links from a given url - by all I mean links referenced by the links and so on. If you are simply trying to extract the href values of links that show up in a given url, this is parsing only.